# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

Tags: python, regex, replace

I have to assimilate some data. The scripts already exist but need to be adjusted to the new data.

So there is a line:

```
head = fn.replace(re.search(r'\d{8}_\d{4}', fn).group(),'')
```

where I get the Error: `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'`

To fix this I need to understand whats actually  is going on at this line.
And I do not understand what is done after the "replace". Can someone explain me whats going on here? What does `r'\d{8}_\d{4}'` mean?

Comment: This is Python, not Bash

Comment: I am sorry, you are right! There are scripts in four or five different languages and I messed it up!

Comment: By the way https://regex101.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

re.search is finding matches of your regex pattern and returns a regex match object. If there are no matches it returns None. So You can't call `.group()` on None.

```
In [38]: re.search(r'921', mystr)
Out[38]: <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(23, 26), match='921'>

In [39]: mystr
Out[39]: "b'la lala 135\\r\\n 1039 921\\r\\n'"

In [40]: re.search(r'921', mystr)
Out[40]: <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(23, 26), match='921'>

In [41]: re.search(r'potatoes', mystr)
```

The `SRE_Match` object has the `group()` method which gets the string value of the match.

```
In [42]: re.search(r'921', mystr).group()
Out[42]: '921'
```

So, if you're still not clear what it's all doing, it's finding the string `fn` that matches the regex pattern provided in `re.search()` and removes it from the string `fn` by replacing it with `''`. In this case it's finding matches in `fn` that have 8 digits(`\d{8}`) followed by an underscore and then 4 more digits(`\d{4}`). so strings that look like `12345678_1234`.

Comment: alright, and the 'group()' returns the whole string?

Comment: Thank you very much! I think I get it! :)

Comment: @Leo group(0) or group() would be the whole matching string

Comment: Sorry, I had to take my dog out. But glad you got it :)